# QString::endsWith() doesn't work?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a function where  I check the ending of a string to determine extension.

I use the method `endsWith` with a second argument: `Qt::CaseInsensitive`.

Now the problem is, for some extensions it works and for others it doesn't. The strings are written only in normal latin characters, nothing special.

In the debugger the strings look ok, there are no trailing whitespaces or anything after the final character.

It should work, yet it only works for some file extensions. Here is a sample of my checks:

```
if(myString.endsWith(".mp3", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || myString.endsWith(".wav", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || myString.endsWith(".flac", Qt::CaseInsensitive) ||
   myString.endsWith(".ape", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

myString is `"Glory.mp3"`

It only works for some file extensions.

Here is a non-working case:

```
else if(myString.endsWith(".zip", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || myString.endsWith(".rar", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || myString.endsWith(".tar", Qt::CaseInsensitive) ||
            myString.endsWith(".tar.gz", Qt::CaseInsensitive), myString.endsWith(".7z", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

myString is `"magnets.zip"`

Comment: Show us the content of both working & non working version of myString please :)

Comment: Why not use [`QFileInfo::completeSuffix`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#completeSuffix) or [`QFileInfo::suffix`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#suffix)?

Comment: I have added examples

@JamesAdkison in the place where I am doing this, I only get a list of strings, so I have to work with that

Comment: `QFileInfo` is constructed with a string... [`QFileInfo::QFileInfo(const QString & file)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#QFileInfo-2)

Comment: Please enhance your post: Display `myString` and later display your condition result (true/false), and send us the output of the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> else if(myString.endsWith(".zip", Qt::CaseInsensitive) ||  myString.endsWith(".rar", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || myString.endsWith(".tar", Qt::CaseInsensitive) ||
>         myString.endsWith(".tar.gz", Qt::CaseInsensitive), myString.endsWith(".7z", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
> {
> ```

Use `||` instead `,` between the last two `endsWith` calls

`,` is an operator that evaluates both sides, but only returns the right side of its expression

Comment: Where is the `,` in original code and where is the fix ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan: It is the second `,` in the second line, and it needs to be replaced by `||`